# Name for games where the i'th player's utility depends only on the actions of players 1 to i?

Tags: game-theory

Consider the class of normal form games with strategy sets S_1, ..., S_n, where each player's utility function depends only on its own and the previous players' strategies. i.e. u_i(s_1,...,s_n) = u'_i(s_1,...,s_i), for some u'.

Is there a name for this class of games?

Comment: I don't know, but notice that for this type of games, you can find the Nash equilibria by sequentially eliminating weakly dominated strategies.

Comment: @tdm, also notice that the normal-form game corresponding to an extensive form game where each player makes one decision (with perfect information) has this structure as well.